# How to arrange the table from left to right in fpdf multicell?

Tags: fpdf

How to arrange the table from left to right in fpdf multicell?

This is my code

```
$pdf->MultiCell(12.5 ,4,'',1);


$pdf->Cell(12.5 ,7,'',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(20 ,7,'',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(60 ,7,'',1,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(25 ,7,'',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(25 ,7,'',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(25 ,7,'',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(70 ,7,'',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(27 ,7,'',1,1,'C');

 // }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mekOX.png)
[image]

And this is the output when i use this code.

```
$pdf->MultiCell(12.5 ,4,'Hello World',1);
$pdf->MultiCell(12.5 ,4,'Hello World',1);

$pdf->Cell(12.5 ,7,'',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(20 ,7,'',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(60 ,7,'',1,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(25 ,7,'',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(25 ,7,'',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(25 ,7,'',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(70 ,7,'',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(27 ,7,'',1,1,'C');

// }

$pdf->Cell(277 ,5,'',0,1,'C');
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGeOK.png)

Comment: Hi, it might be useful to include some of the code you are using that is causing the misalignment

Comment: Hello sir.. I already add my code above.. I don't know where to put the code using multicell to arrange the table form left to right..